# Error in UseMethod("select_")

Tags: r, dplyr

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I'm in an introductory R course and I'm trying to create histograms and summaries for the age of diagnosis with diabetes "diabage2" and their insulin use "insulin" (Yes/No/NA).  The dataset is brfss2013.

My first attempt was `brfss2013 %>% group_by(insulin = "Yes") %>% summarise(MEAN = mean(brfss2013$diabage2, na.rm = TRUE), n = n())`

```
  insulin     MEAN      n
    <chr>    <dbl>  <int>
1     Yes 51.48694 491775
```

Which looks fine, except I know that MEAN and n are reported for the sample mean and n, not the selected part of the sample (I've had this problem in another part of my project - not sure why it's not working.  I can verify that the answer is incorrect.)

When I tried to use subset() and select for only data that met my conditions so I could easily summarise it and make histograms (i.e. one group of data where insulin = yes and one for insulin = no)

```
wInsulin <- subset(brfss2013, insulin = "Yes", select = c(diabage2))
woInsulin <- subset(brfss2013, insulin = "No", select = c(diabage2))
```

These looked the same, even though they shouldn't contain any of the same observations since they're mutually exclusive.

When I tried to use select() to trim down the set I'm using from 330 variables to three, I encountered another problem:

```
InsulinData <- select(brfss2013$insulin, brfss2013$diabage, brfss2013$sex, brfss2013$X_state)
```

gave me the error

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Which I have no idea what to make of.

I feel like I'm missing something very fundamental, but my lack of experience means that I don't have the foundations to understand a lot of solutions to other people's problems and the course thus far has covered more statistical theory than the actual details of dealing with R.  I would really appreciate any guidance I could get.

Comment: `brfss2013` doesn't come with the dplyr package, so you might want to make this more explicitly reproducible. Usually, one would write the code that grabs or loads the dataset, like `library(whatever)`.

Comment: I'm seeing a few mistakes here, like `insulin = "Yes"` instead of `==`; referring to cols with `$` inside a dplyr chain; using `subset` when the dplyr idiom is `filter` (or some similar word). I'd recommend just browsing the R intro doc from the top and going some through examples there: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

You almost had this:

```
InsulinData <- select(brfss2013$insulin, 
                      brfss2013$diabage, 
                      brfss2013$sex, 
                      brfss2013$X_state)
```

Should be:

```
InsulinData <- select(brfss2013, insulin, diabage, sex, X_state)
```

With `dplyr` you only need to specify the data.frame once. `select` thought you were trying to select columns from the variable `brfss2013$insulin`, which you can't.

Also, your first set of intstructions are a bit confusing:

```
group_by(insulin = "yes")
```

You `group_by(insulin)` and you filter rows by `filter(insulin == "yes")`

Probably want something more like:

```
brfss2013 %>% 
  group_by(insulin) %>% 
    summarise(MEAN = mean(diabage2, na.rm = TRUE), n = n())
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this error once, turns out I had unknowingly converted my data.frame into a factor. Check under the global environment under type to see how your data.frame is saved as.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35601444)